# console.log($("#app").html()); return undefined, how come?

Tags: jquery, dom, undefined, console.log

I feel like I've done this a thousand times but now suddenly when I do `console.log($("#app").html());` I get `undefined`, why? Isn't .html() suppose to return what's inside #app?

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/h74saumj/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `#` in `<div id="#app">`. It should be `<div id="app">`.

If you want to keep it, use this selector `$( "[id=#app]" )` instead of `$( "#app" )`.

Comment: @01AutoMonkey such things happen often. Now you have three different solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the meta character like,

```
$("#\\#app").html();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h74saumj/3/)